# Python Instagram error user_search()

Tags: python, instagram

I just got my authentication credentials for Instagram and I've been trying to use the [Python wrapper](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram), but I can't get basic queries to work. For example, after loading my client ID, secret and access token:

```
api = InstagramAPI(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, access_token=access_token)
print('got api %s'%(api))
user_name = 'natgeo'
search_result = api.user_search(q=user_name)
print('username %s gets search result %s'%
      (user_name, search_result))
```

returns

```
username natgeo gets search result []
```

which shouldn't be the case, since `natgeo` is a valid Instagram account. However, searching for my username works fine for some reason. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's possible that you're in [sandbox mode](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/). This will only allow you to access your own account.

Comment: Just checked and I'm indeed in sandbox mode. It looks like I have to fill out a complicated form to get any additional permissions. Any tips for requesting the extra permissions?

Comment: Nah, I've never used the API extensively, I've just seen this problem before. Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you're in [sandbox mode](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/). This means that you can only access the first 20 items of your own profile. Move your app out of sandbox mode to have full access to the API.